# Coloring the boxes created by boxit command

Tags: color, metapost, box

I am trying to change background color and text color of the boxes
made by `boxit.bb1()` and tried to look for `drawoptions` from John Hobby's
manual but I could not find any related to it.
I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Would you provide an example of what you need, please? Without a working example it's impossible to help you

Answer (score 4):

Not to be nasty, but the p. 5 of the [manual](http://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpboxes.pdf) actually says how to add coloring. Just tweak the proposed example:

```
vardef drawpink(text t) =
    fixsize(t);
    forsuffixes s=t:
        %Use another color ad libitum
        fill bpath.s withcolor 3/4[red,white];
        drawboxed(s);
    endfor
enddef;

%Uncomment or change if you work in standalone MetaPost.
%It also works for circleit
%beginfig(1)
boxit.a(btex Box 1 etex);
boxit.b(btex Box 2 etex);
b.n = a.s - (0,20pt);
drawpink(a,b);
drawarrow a.s -- b.n;
%endfig
%end
```

Obviously you'll have to provide specific conditions if that's not what you intend to ask.

[image]

**EDIT**: I've missed your comment on colored text. The following is adapted from `boxes.mp`. You could go ahead with further customization, but it'd result in something too charged.

```
def docoloredboxed(text t)(expr c, cc) =  
  fixsize(t); fixpos(t);
  forsuffixes s=t: 
        draw bpath.s withcolor c; %Frame 
        draw pic_mac_.s withcolor cc; %Text 
    endfor
enddef;

vardef drawcoloredboxed(text t)(expr c, cc, ccc) =
    fixsize(t);
    forsuffixes s=t:
        %Use another color ad libitum
        fill bpath.s withcolor c; %Background
        docoloredboxed(s)(cc, ccc);
    endfor
enddef;

%Uncomment for standalone MetaPost
%beginfig(0);
    boxit.a(btex Box 1 etex);
    boxit.b(btex Box 2 etex);
    b.n = a.s - (0,20pt);
    %Background, frame and text in respective order
    drawcoloredboxed(a,b)(3/4[red,white],red,1/2green);
    drawarrow a.s -- b.n;
%endfig;
%end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you first. And the second, you being nasty totally make sense. But I wonder why not use "drawoptions", it looks more straight forward and no need to make another macro.  Like "drawoptions(fill path withcolor 3/4[red,white])"

Comment: @user1389406 Looking at the implementation of `drawboxed`, it executes several macros before drawing, so maybe a `drawoptions` would be ignored or lost at some point. And I think `drawoptions` has a slightly different syntax, btw.

Comment: Thanks. It gives a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

As you may have discovered, `boxes.mp` hides a certain amount of complexity from you and it is not always very intuitive. So here is a plain alternative, showing you how to create boxes using the built-in path `unitsquare`, and then fill them and draw them, and add coloured labels, using `drawoptions()` as described in the manual.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.%{outputformat}";

beginfig(1);

    path box[];

    box1 = unitsquare xscaled 34 yscaled 13;
    box2 = box1 shifted (21, -55);

    drawoptions(withcolor 7/8[blue, white]);
    fill box1;
    fill box2;

    drawoptions(withcolor 2/3 blue);
    interim ahangle := 30;
    drawarrow center box1 -- center box2 cutbefore box1 cutafter box2;
    
    draw box1;
    draw box2;

    label("First", center box1);
    label("Second", center box2);

    drawoptions();

endfig;
end.
```

If you compile this with `mpost` you should get something like this:

[image]

- Pro tip:  for a slightly shorter arrow, add `bbox` before the target path name.

  ```
        drawarrow center box1 -- center box2 cutbefore box1 cutafter bbox box2;
  ```

[image]